# asp.net webapplication gives error on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to host my app on a server. Running it in visual studio works fine and I see no errors when i publish it localy to a folder.

I then use Filezilla to transfer the files to the server and when I try to use it, it gives me this error.

```
System.MissingMethodException
Method 'CompilerParameters.get_CoreAssemblyFileName' not found.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.
Exception stack trace:

at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.GetCompilationArgume ntString (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x00000] in  <filename unknown>:0 
at  Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.FromFileBatch  (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames)  [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.Type requiredBaseType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.UI.PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance (System.String virtualPath, System.String inputFile, System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String requestType, System.String url, System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url, Boolean ignoreContextHandler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

This is the first time i'm trying this out and I cant figure out what could be wrong.

If I look at my web.config file it says:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
```

Which is the asp version?

The error page also gives me this:

```
Version Information: 4.0.5 (Stable 4.0.5.1/1d8d582 Thu Nov 12 12:03:50 UTC 2015); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
```

So I'm suspecting it has something to do with the versions being different? But I'm really not sure.

Comment: Do you have .NET FW 4.5 installed on target server ?

Comment: Unfortunatly I dont host the server myself. It's a University. When I did a google searh of the server I found the information: X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
and X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

Comment: Unfortunately that has no information value :) this header would be set for both .NET FW 4.5 & .NET FW 4.0 (.NET 4.5 runs on .NET 4.0 "core"). If it is possible try to make small "hello world" web app that uses just .NET 4.0 & upload it to server - if it will run it means your server doesn't have .NET 4.5. Btw. .NET 4.0 support ends on January 12, 2016. So you can ask "authorities" to update .NET on server to keep it updatable with secure patches after the end of support of .NET 4.0.

Comment: That's unfortunate :). Will do! Thanks